# Windows batch renaming

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Currently I am working on a small utility which processes a specific archive format. The question is: suppose I have several files which either match `*.zipped.*` pattern either not. The last asterisk is guaranteed to represent the format (extension). How do I pass all matching files to the utility via Windows .bat-file?

A sample script should be like that:

```
FOR /R "%CD%" %%I IN (*.zipped.*) DO (
 SET file_name=%%I
 offzip %%I !file_name:~end,end-7!%%~xI
)
```

where "offzip" represents the utility I use.
Of course, this one does not help. By the way, extensions may be of different length.

Example cases:

- "sample.zipped.txt" -> "sample.txt"
- "zipped123.zipped.dat" -> "zipped123.dat"
- "abc.zipped.sampleextension" -> "abc.sampleextension"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could do `offzip "%%~I" "!file_name:.zipped.=."`...

Comment: @aschipfl The closing exclamation mark is missing. `offzip "%%~I" "!file_name:.zipped.=.!"`

Comment: You don't need `%CD%`, `/R` recurses the current working directory by default.

Comment: Doing that way: `FOR /R "%CD%" %%I IN (*.zipped.*) DO (SET file_name=%%I   offzip "%%~I" "!file_name:.zipped.=.!")`...  Now it saves the content to the file named "!file_name", with no extention... What am I doing wrong?(  P.S. Cmd/bat do not seem to be that fast and that easy... Funny.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a nested `For` loop to treat `.zipped` as another extension removing it via metavariable expansion:

```bat
For /R %%A In (*.zipped.*) Do For %%B In ("%%~dpnA"
) Do offzip "%%A" "%%~dpnB%%~xA"
```

Comment: Nice one, eliminates the DelayedExpansion.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script below into a file such as zren.ps1, then invoke it using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File zren.ps1
```

=== zren.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter '*.zipped.*' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '.*\.zipped\.[^\.]*$') {
            $newname = $_.Name -replace '\.zipped\.','.'
            & offzip "$_.FullName" "$newname"
        }
    }
```